# Oracle historical reporting - what was the row at a point in time

Tags: oracle, reporting, temporal

I have been asked to run a report of the state of our assets at a fixed point in time (1st Jan 2019).

The way this database has been written is that the asset has its own table with current info and then for various bits of data there is also the history of that info changing, each bit is stored its own "history" table with a start and end date.  So for example one of the bits of info is the asset class - the asset table will have a field that contains the current asset class and then if that class has changed in the past then there will be rows in the asset_history table with start and end dates. Something like...

```
AssetID AssetClass StartDate EndDate
------- ---------- --------- -------
      1          1 12-12-87  23-04-90
      1          5 23-04-90  01-02-00
      1          2 01-02-00  27-01-19
      1          1 27-01-19
```

So this asset has changed classes a few times but I need to write something to be able to check, for each asset, and work out which class was the active class as at 1st Jan.  For this example that would be the second-from last row as it changed to class 2 back in 2000 and then after 1st Jan 2019 it became a class 1.

And to make it more complicated I will need this for several bits of data but if I can get the notion of how to do it right then I'm happy to translate this to the other data.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: so you need a where clause that looks for the date in question being between the start and end dates, or for the end date being null and the date in question being greater than the start date?

Comment: The assetclass could have been set before the startdate as well so that would be a less than

Comment: So you want the asset class for the first row to match against all dates before 12th Dec 1987?

Comment: Sorry, I'm evidently not being clear.  I am being asked to find out what the assetclass was as-at the 1st January.  So I need to write something that checks all assetclass changes and returns the row where either the assetclass has never changed (so startdate would be <= 1st Jan and enddate is null) or the row where the 1st Jan is between the startdate and end date.

Comment: Did you try kfinity’s initial query? If so, how does that query not answer your question?

Comment: I haven't physically had a go (ironically I am on a SQL course this week!) but I will give it a go as soon as I am back at work and can access the database

Comment: Hi, yes that does appear to work on the handful of tests I did.  I've marked it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually write this like

```
select assetClass
from history_table h
 where :point_in_time >= startDate
   and (:point_in_time < endDate
        or endDate is null)
```

(assuming that those columns are actually `date` type and not `varchar2`)

`between` always seems tempting, but it includes both endpoints, so you'd have to write something like `:point_in_time between startDate and (endDate - interval '1' second)`

EDIT: If you try to run this query with a point_in_time *before your first start_date*, you won't get any results. That seems normal to me, but maybe instead you want to pick "the first result which hasn't expired yet", like this:

```
select assetClass
from history_table h
 where (:point_in_time < endDate
        or endDate is null)
order by startDate asc
fetch first 1 row only
```

Comment: Thanks, that wouldn't work if the startdate was before the point_in_time though does it? If say the assetclass was changed on 1st December 2018 and then changed again at the end of January 19.

Comment: Oh, you mean if the point_in_time was before the startdate. No, I kinda figured that was the point of a startdate. But I'll edit my answer to add an option for that.

Comment: Hi. The statdate will potentially occur multiple times because poentially the assetclass could change multiple times but I am being asked to find out what the assetclass was at a specific time.  Essentially I need to write something that checks all assetclass changes and returns the row where either the assetclass has never changed (so startdate would be <= 1st Jan and enddate is null) or the row where the 1st Jan is between the startdate and end date.

Comment: hi. thanks for this, I didn't think it would work but it does.